# 'modulate for' - an unconventional but tolerated verb-preposition combination?

Tags: creative-writing

Calling all gifted writers, would you tolerate 'modulate for' in this paragraph?

"Dr. Tom wants the best for everybody who asks him for help. Despite his impressive skills and the physical interventions, Dr. Tom is foremostly concerned with the patient’s spirit, as his work is a spiritual treatment that in turn might modulate for the patient’s healthy body and mind."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Omit *for*

The problem is that *modulate* means that something *modulates* something else. Your sentence reads as if you want to say that the spiritual treatment might change the patient's already healthy body and mind, depending on the mental state of the patient. Therefore you can just use *modulate* without any other word being necessary.

> his work is a spiritual treatment that in turn might modulate [<s>for</s>] the patient’s healthy body and mind

You wouldn't normally use *modulate* together with *for*. In your example it sounds wrong and is difficult to read.